# GET MAXIMUM VALUE FROM A GROUP OF DATA

Tags: sql-server

I have data in table like below, and need to get records for distinct MPSOBTID that has maximum MID 
eg: MPSOBTID=5929 getMID=5 and so on

```
ID      MID     MPSOBTID         EmpID           DesgID 
7        2        5897            957            629            
8        2        5898            544            604            
9        2        5896            544            604        
10       3        5929            961            590        
11       3        5930            120            604    
12       3        5931            1009           604    
16       4        5929            961            590        
17       4        5930            120            604    
18       5        5929            961            590        
19       5        5930            120            604    
20       5        5931            1009           604    
24       6        5903            544            604    
25       6        5904            957            629    
26       6        5905            544            604
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a simple group by query like below 
<kbd>**[see working demo](http://rextester.com/ELQ92707)**</kbd>

```
select MPSOBTID,MAX(MID) maximumMID
from yourTable
group by MPSOBTID
```

If you need all data for this maximumMID record you can join back on the table and get data like below query

```
select T.* from yourTable T
inner join 
( 
    select MPSOBTID,MAX(MID) maximumMID
    from yourTable
    group by MPSOBTID
)T1
on T.MID=T1.maximumMID 
and T.MPSOBTID = T1.MPSOBTID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer.It help me very well

Comment: @satheesh Thank you. Please also accept this as answer so that future seekers of similar question can benefit by knowing they can rely on this answer